# Boolean variables becoming true for seemingly no reason

Tags: javascript, html

```js
var Number1 = 0
var Number2 = 0
var ZeroVAR = "0"
var OneVAR = "1"
var TwoVAR = "2"
var ThreeVAR = "3"
var FourVAR = "4"
var FiveVAR = "5"
var SixVAR = "6"
var SevenVAR = "7"
var EightVAR = "8"
var NineVAR = "9"
var EquationN1 = 0
var EquationN2 = 0
var AddVAR = false
var SubtractVAR = false
var MultiplyVAR = false
var DiviseVAR = false
var Output = false

function Zero() {
  Number1 = Number1 + ZeroVAR;
}

function One() {
  Number1 = Number1 + OneVAR;
}

function Two() {
  Number1 = Number1 + TwoVAR;
}

function Three() {
  Number1 = Number1 + ThreeVAR;
}

function Four() {
  Number1 = Number1 + FourVAR;
}

function Five() {
  Number1 = Number1 + FiveVAR;
}

function Six() {
  Number1 = Number1 + SixVAR;
}

function Seven() {
  Number1 = Number1 + SevenVAR;
}

function Eight() {
  Number1 = Number1 + EightVAR;
}

function Nine() {
  Number1 = Number1 + NineVAR;
}

function Ok1() {
  SetNumber1();
}

function SetNumber1() {
  EquationN1 = Number1;
  console.log(Number1)

}

function Add() {
  AddVAR = true
}

function Subtract() {
  SubtractVAR = true
}

function Multiply() {
  MultiplyVAR = true
}

function Divise() {
  DiviseVAR = true
}

function Zero2() {
  Number2 = Number2 + ZeroVAR;
}

function One2() {
  Number2 = Number2 + OneVAR;
}

function Two2() {
  Number2 = Number2 + TwoVAR;
}

function Three2() {
  Number2 = Number2 + ThreeVAR;
}

function Four2() {
  Number2 = Number2 + FourVAR;
}

function Five2() {
  Number2 = Number2 + FiveVAR;
}

function Six2() {
  Number2 = Number2 + SixVAR;
}

function Seven2() {
  Number2 = Number2 + SevenVAR;
}

function Eight2() {
  Number2 = Number2 + EightVAR;
}

function Nine2() {
  Number2 = Number2 + NineVAR;
}

function Ok2() {
  SetNumber2();
}

function SetNumber2() {
  EquationN2 = Number2;
  console.log(Number2);
  InitiateCalculation();

}

function InitiateCalculation() {

  if (AddVAR = true) {
    Output = parseInt(EquationN1) + parseInt(EquationN2);
    console.log(Output);
  }
  if (SubtractVAR = true) {
    Output = EquationN1 - EquationN2;
    console.log(Output);
  }

  if (MultiplyVAR = true) {
    Output = EquationN1 * EquationN2;
    console.log(Output);
  }

  if (DiviseVAR = true) {
    Output = EquationN1 / EquationN2;
    console.log(Output);
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <div id="Zero"><button onclick="Zero()">0</button></div>
  <div id="One"><button onclick="One()">1</button></div>
  <div id="Two"><button onclick="Two()">2</button></div>
  <div id="Three"><button onclick="Three()">3</button></div>
  <div id="Four"><button onclick="Four()">4</button></div>
  <div id="Five"><button onclick="Five()">5</button></div>
  <div id="Six"><button onclick="Six()">6</button></div>
  <div id="Seven"><button onclick="Seven()">7</button></div>
  <div id="Eight"><button onclick="Eight()">8</button></div>
  <div id="Nine"><button onclick="Nine()">9</button></div>
  <div id="Ok1"><button onclick="Ok1()">OK</button></div>

  <div id="Add"><button onclick="Add()">+</button></div>
  <div id="Subtract"><button onclick="Subtract()">-</button></div>
  <div id="Multiply"><button onclick="Multiply()">x</button></div>
  <div id="Divise"><button onclick="Divise()">÷</button></div>

  <div id="Zero2"><button onclick="Zero2()">0</button></div>
  <div id="One2"><button onclick="One2()">1</button></div>
  <div id="Two2"><button onclick="Two2()">2</button></div>
  <div id="Three2"><button onclick="Three2()">3</button></div>
  <div id="Four2"><button onclick="Four2()">4</button></div>
  <div id="Five2"><button onclick="Five2()">5</button></div>
  <div id="Six2"><button onclick="Six2()">6</button></div>
  <div id="Seven2"><button onclick="Seven2()">7</button></div>
  <div id="Eight2"><button onclick="Eight2()">8</button></div>
  <div id="Nine2"><button onclick="Nine2()">9</button></div>
  <div id="Ok2"><button onclick="Ok2()">OK</button></div>
</head>

</html>
```

My creation is a basic calculator. However whenever the `SetNumber2` function goes through (the one which initiates `InitiateCalculation()` function), all the variables `AddVAR`, `SubtractVAR`, `MultiplyVAR` and `DiviseVAR` are set to true, even though the if statements within them should have made the conditions applied earlier (Button press changes to true) have not been changed. It is as if they are entirely pointless because at the end of the code all of the values are set to true.

Comment: Just a note: I think you could benefit from the notion of *function arguments* and reduce the number of functions you have by 90%.

Comment: Why are you storing your numbers as strings?

Comment: a list of console.log's do the same with less lines of code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're setting each of these variables to `true` in your `if` statements. You need to use `===` to check for equality instead of using `=`, which is the assignment operator.

```
if (AddVAR === true) {
    Output = parseInt(EquationN1) + parseInt(EquationN2);
    console.log(Output);
}
```

You'll need to do this for each of your `if` statements.

You *could* use `==` instead of `===`, but this is generally frowned upon because it is not type-sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

In every if statement you are using assignment operator instead of equality operator

change `if (AddVAR = true) {` to `if (AddVAR == true) {`
or to `if (AddVAR === true) {`

and similarly for other `if` statements

Comment: `==` is frowned upon.